# exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use 'rubyoverflow' gem in rails:

```
begin
  puts "=== 1 ==="
  qt = Questions.retrieve_by_tag(tag).questions
  puts "=== 2 ==="
rescue
  puts "=== 3 ==="
end
```

But sometimes I get the error on the console:

> couldn't parse YAML at line 843 column 4
>
> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in`parse_stream' ... rubyoverflow
>   (1.0.1) lib/rubyoverflow.rb:86:in `request' ...
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`block in start_thread'

But the question not about the error in the gem, but about the exception handling.  I get in the console only line:

```
  puts "=== 1 ==="
```

but not lines

```
  puts "=== 2 ==="
  puts "=== 3 ==="
```

why?

How can I restore esecution of my program if the line

```
  qt = Questions.retrieve_by_tag(tag).questions
```

fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `rescue` traps `StandardError` and whatever inherits from it.

From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000030):

> By default, rescue only intercepts StandardError and its descendants...

The exception being raised is probably not that, so rescue doesn't handle it.

Usually you can figure out what to use as rescue's parameter from the docs to the method raising it, but, if not, you can use

```
rescue Exception => e
  print e.to_s
end
```

to see what the exception is, then replace `Exception` with that value.

More information is on the internet, but here's a piece of code to [print a list of Exceptions](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy).

Comment: That's not it. Notice it is an exception being thrown on another thread: `/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in start_thread'`. I ran into the same problem with rsolr Sunspot. It creates a callback on the model save, and it seems there is no way to catch it! I tried to catch the specific exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED`, and also `Exception`, but it still fails. The stack trace doesn't list any of my code whatsoever. It is all framework code, from Webbrick down to rack down to rsolr.